# Question marks in MySQL DB JavaEE Glassfish

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I am developing JEE a project. I use the Glassfish server and MySQL database and EJB components. When I write from a server to database english characters, everything works perfectly (All the characters in the database are displayed correctly). But if I try to write from a server to database Cyrillic (eg Ukrainian symbols) they are displayed in database as a question marks (??????). (If I write a Cyrillic characters in database **manually** everything is displayed correctly). How can I rectify this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. I solved the problem. 
   In Ubuntu MySQL installed whith encoding latin1. To boot from the server immediately encoding UTF-8, you need to edit the file / etc / mysql / my.cnf:

```
    1) In the [mysqld] section, add the following lines:
            skip-character-set-client-handshake
            character-set-server = utf8
            init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
            collation-server=utf8_general_ci

    2) It is also desirable to set the encoding for the client and mysqldump. To do this in the sections [client] and [mysqldump] need to add the line:
            default-character-set=utf8

    3) Restart the server MySQL.

    4) Enjoy :)
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point in the process the wrong encoding is being used, most likely something like ISO-8859-1 which doesn't support those characters.

You need to check each step in the chain (i.e. database drivers, database, database server, web page encoding, etc) to identify where the corruption occurs and then change the configuration on that link.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your MySQL database is not encoded properly. By default, Java uses UTF so you can try to create your mysql db with:

```
CREATE DATABASE `mydb` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

For me it helped.